# What is the command line to install the latest version of a Nuget package XYZ into XYZ\1.2.3 folder?

Tags: nuget

I have the following Powershell script:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]$PackageId,
    $PackagesDir = "$env:USERPROFILE\.nuget\packages",
    $Flavour = 'net462',
    $Source)

if (-not (Test-Path "$PackagesDir\nuget.exe"))
{
    mkdir $PackagesDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    curl -Uri "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe" -OutFile "$PackagesDir\nuget.exe"          
}

if ($Source)
{
    $SourceSwitch = "-Source","$Source"
}
&"$PackagesDir\nuget.exe" install $PackageId -OutputDirectory $PackagesDir -NonInteractive $SourceSwitch

$PkgDir = $(&"$PackagesDir\nuget.exe" list $PackageId -source $PackagesDir) -replace ' ','.'
$Base = "$PackagesDir\$PkgDir\lib\$Flavour\$PackageId"
@{
    Path = (dir "$Base.dll","$Base.exe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName
}
```

It does the following:

1. Downloads nuget.exe if not found under the package directory
2. Installs the given package under the package directory. So for the package XYZ having the latest version of 1.2.3 it creates a directory XYZ.1.2.3 under the given package dir.
3. Tries to guess the path to the main package assembly and returns it.

I want the package to be in XYZ\1.2.3 rather than in XYZ.1.2.3

How do I do it?

P.S.

I will be happy for any other improvements to the script, because I am new to nuget and might be doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the nuget add command as described here - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-add

This layout is called hierarchical source.